# Errors occurring when attempting to run grunt serve on Yeoman scaffolding

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to run `grunt serve` on Yeoman scaffolding and this keeps happening:

```
Gizmo:testapp brianwalborn$ grunt connect
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-connect" not found. Is it installed?
Loading "imagemin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'imagemin-gifsicle'
>> Local Npm module "grunt-mocha" not found. Is it installed?
Warning: Task "connect" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2014-10-23 06:07:08 UTC)
loading tasks  859ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 100%
Total 860ms
```

I've seen a lot of questions but none with this error message. I'm assuming it's just something that I'm simply missing. Does anyone have any advice on what could be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run `npm install` to install dependencies?  Do these modules appear in the node_modules directory?

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed the npm packages with the same user you are running the grunt tasks ?

Maybe grunt is looking in an empty npm cache_folder.

Another things you could try are this:

1. Update to the last grunt-contrib-connect and/or grunt-contrib-imagemin versions
2. Clean the npm cache, this is the command: `npm cache clear`
3. If you are running Linux, be sure you installed the build-essential package. (https://askubuntu.com/questions/398489/how-to-install-build-essential)